# Angular Material autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

So I am trying to create an Angular Material Autocomplete. Currently I have it working so the options are showing up. When I click on them, the correct name is placed in the input.

Now I need to extend this, when the user is typing the possible options need to be filtered. I was following the Angular Material tutorial but I keep getting errors.

I keep getting: `An argument for 'callbackfn' was not provided.`when I try to use my filteredOptions.

Also after I finish this, the next step would be, the name has to be put in the first input and the corresponding phoneNumber has to be placed in the next input. I am currently unsure how to start with this problem so suggestions are welcome!

IDriverDate interface:

```
export interface IDriverData {
    name: string;
    phone: string;
}
```

messages.component.ts:

My driver data is inside driverData, I am honestly unsure why I need to use filteredOptions and I can't do this straight on the data.

```
driverData: IDriverData[];
filteredOptions: Observable<IDriverData[]>;



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessages();

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(driver => typeof driver === 'string' ? driver : driver.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.driverData.slice())
      );
   }

displayFn(driver): string {
    return driver ? driver.name : driver;
  }

private _filter(name: string): IDriverData[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.driverData.filter(driver => driver.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

messages.component.html:

```
<div>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Verstuur een bericht:</mat-card-title>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-content>
            <div class="input">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Naam" [(ngModel)]="name" [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let driver of driverData" [value]="driver">
                            {{driver.name}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Telefoonnummer" type="tel" [(ngModel)]="number">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <mat-divider class="subdivider"></mat-divider>
            <div class="message">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <textarea id="message" matInput placeholder="Bericht: " rows=10 [(ngModel)]="content"></textarea>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="sendMessages()">Verstuur</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your mat-option element, you no longer iterate through the entire array of driverData, you should now iterate through the Observable filteredOptions array, along with the async pipe:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let driver of filteredOptions | async" [value]="driver">
```

And then to capture your selection and populate, I like to use optionSelected event.  You could then pull the values from your FormControl into your this.number variable.  I wouldn't put the [(ngModel)]="name" on the input though, it already has a FormControl.  Inputs should only use ngModel or FormControls, not both.

```
(optionSelected)="driverSelected()"
```

And then in driverSelected:

```
public driverSelected(): void {
    const driver = this.mycontrol.value;
    this.number = driver.number;
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks for the help! Made a small edit to your answer, if you agree please accept or change as needed. After that I can accept this as the correct answer!

Comment: Hmm, looking at the official documenation (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api) for Angular Material 8.2.3, the output event is @Output() optionSelected: EventEmitter<MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent>.